# Uploading a binary file to a filestream enabled table using VBScript (from cmd)

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, upload, vbscript, filestream

I want to insert a binary file into a filestream enabled (remote) database using VBScript (from cmd prompt, using cscript). My code works when I'm testing on my local db, but because the code was using:

```
INSERT........ * FROM OPENROWSET(BULK '"&objFile.Path&"', SINGLE_BLOB)
```

the file has to be a local file (i.e. on the machine the SQL server is on). I need to upload from my machine to a remote SQL file.
Here's where I got to so far:
    Wscript.Echo "Attempting to upload "& objFile.Name &" from folder "& objsubFolder.Name

```
binstream.open
binstream.LoadFromFile objFile.Path

myCommand.CommandText = "INSERT INTO DBNAME (TimeStamp, FileName, Data)" &_
"SELECT '"&objsubFolder.Name&"' AS TimeStamp," &_
"'"&objFile.Name&"' AS FileName," &_
"'"&binstream.Read&"' AS Data"
myCommand.Execute

binstream.close
```

However the error I get returned is:
"Microsoft VBScript runtime error: Type mismatch"

Which I presume is me being silly because I'm trying to insert a binary file by just sticking it into the insert sql statement. How do I work around this and get it to upload my file?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

IMO The easiest way is keeping your code that works for uploading a local file since that works and make sure the file is local by copying the file to the server first on a share. Then run the sql you tested from your script on the server, the copying could also be done from the server if the user which runs the script has sufficient privileges to access your file on the other pc or by putting it on a share that can be read. Executing the script on the server can be done by a schedule, a script that monitors a folder or by remote scripting or PSFILE

Comment: Thanks peter, I was hoping that there would be a way to upload the file via VBScript, as it is somewhat redundant in my case to network share a file for a DB, then access the DB from the same network from another computer, when I can just access the shared file.

Comment: you would only just once share a map but i get your point, hope you find the solution, please publish what you have done in the end